# Installing a custom lighttpd.conf in Yocto

Tags: yocto, lighttpd, openembedded

I want to bake a custom Linux with a lighttpd.conf where cgi is enabled by installing my own lighttpd.conf (or alternatively modify the lighttpd.service and start lighttpd with my customized conf). But both ways lead to the same error:

> file /lib/systemd/system/lighttpd.service conflicts between attempted installs of lighttpd-service-0.1-r0.aarch64 and lighttpd-1.4.59-r0.aarch64

This is my lighttpd-service_0.1.bb

```
SUMMARY = "Modified Lighttpd systemd service"
LICENSE = "CLOSED"

FILESEXTRAPATHS_prepend := "${THISDIR}/files:"
SRC_URI = "file://lighttpd.service"

do_install() {
    install -d ${D}${systemd_unitdir}/system/
    install -m 0644 ${WORKDIR}/lighttpd.service ${D}${systemd_unitdir}/system/lighttpd.service
}

FILES_${PN} += "${systemd_unitdir}/system/lighttpd.service"
```

What is the correct way to overwrite an existing file?
And how can I make sure, that my overwrite is processed after the lighttpd-recipe (otherwise processing lighttpd would probably overwrite my file with the same name)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another approach is to put a file in /etc/lighttpd/conf.d/99-custom.conf in which you append or override lighttpd.conf directives without having to modify the lighttpd.conf file.

Print your lighttpd config using: `lighttpd -f /etc/lighttpd/lighttpd.conf -p`

Comment: So easy :-) In my case, I had to put the 99-custom.conf into /etc/lighttpd.d folder. For future readers: The exact location can be found in the very last line of the original lighttpd.conf file, where all the customizations are loaded. The final trick was to use server.modules += ( "mod_fastcgi", ) as resetting the server.modules variable with '=' leads to a completely confusing error message (syntax error near EOL).

Answer (score 1):

Disable the lighttpd.service which is installed as part of the lighttpd package, and install your service as my-custom-lighttpd.service (or any name other than 'lighttpd.service'.  You can have a custom package containing my-custom-lighttpd.service, and have your custom package depend on the lighttpd package.

Comment: I like both solutions. Had to pick one :-)